# ADO.NET connection string and password with "=" in it

Tags: mysql, ado.net, connection-string

How do I build a connection string which includes a passsword having a "=" in it? (I'm connecting to MySql 5.1)

For example, let's say the password is "Ge5f8z=6", what would the connection string look like?

I tried:

```
Server=DBSERV;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD="Ge5f8z=6";
```

and

```
Server=DBSERV;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD=Ge5f8z=6;"
```

Both don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two == signs.

So it would be

```
  Server=DBSERV;Database=mydb;UID=myuser;PWD=Ge5f8z==6;"
```

Comment: You can use "" to escape : or ;

Comment: @Nix I tried `string connstr = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;User=root;Password=\"t;jd\";";` to connect to mysql db, however, it doesn't work. I've read the page @CResults posted, and here is a quote `To include values that contain a semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the value must be enclosed in double quotes. ` am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Precede it with another =, so `Ge5f8z==6` should work

Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(VS.71).aspx